# Foursquare always tracks geolocation (even when it's turned off)

Tags: ios, iphone, core-location, foursquare

Foursquare always tracks geolocation (even when it's turned off).

On the image you can see that it tracks geolocation right now, but I turned it off, so when I double press home button I don't see Foursquare app.

[image]

Is it but of iOS7, is it bug of my iPhone?

Or may be Apple provided Foursquare with these abilities?

Comment: Applications can track your location in the background if you give them permission - even when they are not running. You can turn off background processing through your device settings and of course block Foursquare from tracking you by turning off the switch in your image. Did you have a programming question?

Comment: The app is not running in the background, because it's turned off (I know the difference between running in the background and to be turned off). To turn it off I pressed home twice and slide the program, so it disappeared

Comment: My programming question is how to track location simular to Foursquare when the app is turned off (not running in the background)

Answer (score 1):

You can find out information on using location in the background in the Apple [Location and Maps programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW10). Although your application doesn't appear in the app switcher it can still receive notifications - just as an app that isn't "running" can display notifications on the lock screen or update its icon badge.

From the Core allocation documentation on Signficant Region Change Notification -

> If you start this service and your application is subsequently terminated, the system automatically relaunches the application into the background if a new event arrives. In such a case, the options dictionary passed to the locationManager:didUpdateLocations: method of your application delegate contains the key UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey to indicate that your application was launched because of a location event. Upon relaunch, you must still configure a location manager object and call this method to continue receiving location events. When you restart location services, the current event is delivered to your delegate immediately. In addition, the location property of your location manager object is populated with the most recent location object even before you start location services.

So, just because you have terminated the app and it doesn't appear in the app switcher doesn't mean that iOS can't relaunch it to process the notification and then shut it down again

Comment: as I said in comments: The app is not running in the background, because it's turned off (I know the difference between running in the background and to be turned off). To turn it off I pressed home twice and slide the program, so it disappeared

Comment: About "So, just because you have terminated the app and it doesn't appear in the app switcher doesn't mean that iOS can't relaunch it to process the notification and then shut it down again".  But it's always tracks location, during 5 days already, so it can't be just because of processing events.

Comment: How else would it track location?  There are no "secret" APIs.